# Delete row from a huge csv file in python

Tags: python, csv

I have a huge(240mb) csv file in which the top 2 rows are junk data.I want to remove this junk data and use the data starting after that.

I would like to know what the best options are .Since its a large file creating a copy of the file and editing it would be a time taking process. 
Below is the csv eg:-

```
    junk,,,
    ,,,,
    No,name,place,destination
    1,abx,India,SA
```

What I would like to have is

```
 No,name,place,destination
 1,abx,India,SA
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just throw those lines away.

Use Dictreader to parse the header

```
import csv

with open("filename") as fp:
  fp.readline()
  fp.readline()

  csvreader = csv.DictReader(fp, delimiter=',')
  for row in csvreader:
    #your code here
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with tail quite easily

```
tail -n+3 foo > result.data
```

You said top 3 rows but the example has remove the top 2?

```
tail -n+2 foo > result.data
```

You can find more ways here

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37790/how-do-i-delete-the-first-n-lines-of-an-ascii-file-using-shell-commands

Answer (score 1):

Due to the way file systems work, you cannot simply delete the lines from the file directly. Any method to do so will necessarily involve rewriting the entire file with the offending lines removed.

To be safe, before deleting your old file, you'll want store the new file temporarily until you are sure the new one has been successfully created. And if you want to avoid reading the entire large file into memory, you'll want to use a generator.

Here's a generator that returns every item from an iterable (such as a file-like object) after a certain number of items have already been returned:

```
def gen_after_x(iterable, x):
    # Python 3:
    yield from (item for index,item in enumerate(iterable) if index>=x)
    # Python 2:
    for index,item in enumerate(iterable):
        if index>=x:
            yield item
```

To make things simpler, we'll create a function to write the temporary file:

```
def write_file(fname, lines):
    with open(fname, 'w') as f:
        for line in lines:
            f.write(line + '\n')
```

We will also need the `os.remove` and `os.rename` functions from the `os` module to delete the source file and rename the temp file. And we'll need `copyfile` from `shutil` to make a copy, so we can safely delete the source file.

Now to put it all together:

```
from os import remove, rename
from shutil import copyfile

src_file = 'big_file'
tmp_file = 'big_file_temp'
skip = 2

with open(src_file) as fin:
    olines = gen_after_x(fin, skip)
    write_file(tmp_file, olines)

src_file_copy = src_file + '_copy'
copyfile(src_file, src_file_copy)

try:
    remove(src_file)
    rename(tmp_file, src_file)
    remove(src_file_copy)
except Exception:
    try:
        copyfile(src_file_copy, src_file)
        remove(src_file_copy)
        remove(tmp_file)
    except Exception: 
        pass
    raise
```

However, I would note that 240 MB isn't such a huge file these days; you may find it faster to do this the usual way since it cuts down on repetitive disk writes:

```
src_file = 'big_file'
tmp_file = 'big_file_temp'
skip = 2

with open(src_file) as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

for _ in range(skip):
    lines.pop(0)

with open(tmp_file, 'w') as f:
    f.write('\n'.join(lines))

src_file_copy = src_file + '_copy'
copyfile(src_file, src_file_copy)

try:
    remove(src_file)
    rename(tmp_file, src_file)
    remove(src_file_copy)
except Exception:
    try:
        copyfile(src_file_copy, src_file)
        remove(src_file_copy)
        remove(tmp_file)
    except Exception: 
        pass
    raise
```

...or if you prefer the more risky way:

```
with open(src_file) as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

for _ in range(skip):
    lines.pop(0)

with open(src_file, 'w') as f:
    f.write('\n'.join(lines))
```